# How to update XmlNode InnerXml

Tags: c#, xml

I have a `XmlNode` in which I updated one of the 'Node'. Now I want to update my original Node with the new one with changed value but I am not able to do so. Here is the code:

```
XmlNode parametersNode = p_xmlServiceRequest.SelectSingleNode("//Parameters");
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(parametersNode.OuterXml);

XmlNode nodeXML = doc.SelectSingleNode("/Parameters/Parameter[@Name='PolNum']");
nodeXML.Attributes["Value"].Value.Replace('g','G');
```

How can I update my `parametersNode` with new value of `nodeXML`?

Comment: `String.Replace` will not replace the existing value, but return a new string with the replaced values. You need to assign that new value.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer How can we do that ?

Comment: You mean *"How do I assign a value in C#"*?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer I meant how to assign `parametersNode.InnerXml`
 with new value of `nodeXML`

Comment: I don't see you using `InnerXml` anywhere in your code. I thought you only want to replace the attribute value? Or rather: why don't you just edit the original (omit the `doc.Load`)?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer I have to update `parametersNode.InnerXml` with `nodeXML`

Comment: Again: Why not just work with the original when you plan on putting the edited data back again?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Could you please guide me how to update my above code,,I am not able to figure out..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151604/discussion-between-lara-and-manfred-radlwimmer).

Comment: Ok, maybe this will help you see what I'm talking about: You have `p_xmlServiceRequest` (an XmlDocument or XmlNode). You select a node via XPath, convert it to a string (`OuterXml`), convert it back to `XmlDocument` (`doc.LoadXml`), select a sub-node of the original node, call a non-modifying function (`Replace`) on a value-type (string), do **nothing** with the result, and now you want to replace the original node by converting the XmlNode to a string again and setting `InnerXml` ... there are so many unnecessary steps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of your code is unnecessary and can be removed. The main problem is, that `Replace` doesn't replace the original value but returns a new string with the replaced value. Unless there are other problems, this should work:

```
XmlNode nodeXML = p_xmlServiceRequest.SelectSingleNode("//Parameters/Parameter[@Name='PolNum']");
nodeXML.Attributes["Value"].Value = nodeXML.Attributes["Value"].Value.Replace('g','G');
```